# How to enforce Spring Security as main Security Manager?

Tags: spring, spring-security, securitymanager

is there any way to enable java SecurityManager while using spring security ?
I have a Swing standalone application and using spring jdbcDaoImpl to authenticate and authorize using MySql Database (default spring security schema)

but I want to know how to force all tasks be secured, like what happens in setting System.setSecurityManager(...)

Comment: What's the problem with using System.setSecurityManager( <Spring Securtiy>)?

Comment: @MasterCassim well I just don't know ho to do so, what should I set instead of <Spring Security> ? do we have any SecurityManager extensions in Spring?

Comment: Why do you need to set a securtiy mananger then?

Comment: @MasterCassim Hmm, really I don't know is it needed or not? but as I told in main question, I want to enforce security controls all around my application. is there any other way?